# Crystal Reports data comparison side by side

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns, crosstab

I need to create a Crystal Report which will show yearly data side by side, plus the difference in the yearly values and the percentages. I think I can manage the difference and the percentage parts, but am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to put the yearly values side by side.

```
FY2013                      FY2014
(Station) (Item) (Total) (Station) (Item) (Total) (Difference in total)...
data       data   data    data      data   data    data
```

Please help.

Comment: Now I realize that the example I posted is a crap....

Comment: use crosstab...

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into crosstab right now. would you know how I could separate years and put each year in a separate column along with its data in the crosstab?

Comment: check answer,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Create a formula `year`

```
year(Date)
```

Now create a cross tab and then for column part take formula `Year` first and then drag the next level fields.

Let me know in case more queries

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure this one out myself with a formula, but I will keep this in mind in case mine fails.
I do have one more question, though. I got the years separated and its corresponding data, but how do I get the difference in between one data and the other? There is no specific column name for each data and I am not sure how to formulate this one...
Thanks!!!

Comment: Certainly! My formula went something like this:                           
`if {Command.fiscal_year} = {?year1} then {Command.fiscal_year}
else {?year2}`
Strangely enough, it worked.